# How do I fix this query to multiply a column value

Tags: mysql, subquery

I have this table

```
select * from points

+---------+------+------+
| NAME    | Type | RANK |
+---------+------+------+
| A       | H    |  90  |
| A       | M    | 100  |
| A       | H    | N/A  |
| A       | H    | N/A  |
| A       | H    | N/A  |
| B       | H    | 100  |
| B       | M    | 100  |
| B       | L    | 100  |
| C       | H    |  85  |
| C       | M    | 100  |
+---------+------+------+
```

**I'm using this query**

```
SELECT name,
       CAST(
       (      -- only have H, or only have M, or only have L:
         CASE WHEN  `# of H` = 0  AND  `# of M` = 0  THEN  100 * `# of active L` / `# of L`
              WHEN  `# of H` = 0  AND  `# of L` = 0  THEN  100 * `# of active M` / `# of M`
              WHEN  `# of M` = 0  AND  `# of L` = 0  THEN  100 * `# of active H` / `# of H`
              -- only have H & M, or only have H & L, or only have M & L:
              WHEN  `# of H` = 0  THEN  60 * `# of active M` / `# of M` + 40 * `# of active L` / `# of L`
              WHEN  `# of M` = 0  THEN  90 * `# of active H` / `# of H` + 20 * `# of active L` / `# of L`
              WHEN  `# of L` = 0  THEN  80 * `# of active H` / `# of H` + 20 * `# of active M` / `# of M`
              -- have all three:
              ELSE  70 * `# of active H` / `# of H` + 20 * `# of active M` / `# of M` + 10 * `# of active L` / `# of L`
         END
       ) AS SIGNED ) AS score
  FROM ( SELECT name,
                SUM(IF(         type = 'H', 1, 0))  AS `# of H`,
                SUM(IF(rank AND type = 'H', 1, 0))  AS `# of active H`,
                SUM(IF(         type = 'M', 1, 0))  AS `# of M`,
                SUM(IF(rank AND type = 'M', 1, 0))  AS `# of active M`,
                SUM(IF(         type = 'L', 1, 0))  AS `# of L`,
                SUM(IF(rank AND type = 'L', 1, 0))  AS `# of active L`
           FROM points
          GROUP BY name
       ) t
 ORDER
    BY name
;
```

**I get this Output**

```
+---------+-------+
| NAME    | SCORE |
+---------+-------+
| A       |   60  | <--[(2xH)=40 + (1xM)=20] =60
| B       |  100  | <--[(1xH)=70 + (1xM)=20 + (1xL)=10] =100
| C       |  100  | <--[(1xH)=80 + (1xM)=20] =100
+---------+-------+
```

**I need this Desired output**

```
+---------+-------+
| NAME    | SCORE |
+---------+-------+
| A       |   36  | <--[70/4=(17.5 per H) therefore (17.5)*(rank of that h: 90%)=15.75 + (M values, which equals 20/1 =20 Therefore: rank of that m:100% * 20 = 100) = 36 rounded
| B       |  100  | <--[(1xH)=70 + (1xM)=20 + (1xL)=10] =100
| C       |   88  | <--[(1xH)=80 + (1xM)=20] =100
+---------+-------+
```

**Computations required:**

- Type can have only three values: {H, M, L};
- When all values are present, they are graded as followed:

  **H=70 M=20 L=10**
- If an name has more than one kind of Type (H, M, or L) then points are distributed as followed:
- **H/(number of H) ; M/(number of M); L/(number of L)**

-- Example: A has 4 H therefore 70 / 4 = 17.5 for each H

- But some names have a complete set with out having all 'Types.
  -- example : C has Type values: 'H&M` only
- Now Type 'H' and 'M' have to equal 100 for C.

So when only 'H` and 'M' are present they are graded as followed:

**H=80 M=20**

- Equally if another animal comes along with only two Type values M & L they will be graded as followed:

**M=60 L=40**

- Equally if another animal comes along with only two Type values H & L they will be graded as followed:

**H=90 L=10**

And also

- if only H is presnet **H=100**
- if only M is presnet **M=100**
- if only L is presnet **L=100**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks familiar. :-)

Your description is inconsistent in a number of places — for example, your "desired output" for `A` uses `70` and `20`, even though no `A`s have type `L` — but if you mean what I think you do, then the main change you need is to change `` SUM(IF(rank AND type = 'H', 1, 0))  AS `# of active H` `` to `` SUM(IF(type = 'H', rank / 100.0, 0))  AS `rank of H` `` (and likewise for `M` and `L`), and change all references to `` `# of active H` `` to refer to `` `rank of H` `` instead. This way each record will be included in proportion to its rank, rather than being an all-or-nothing thing.

You'll also want to use [`ROUND`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_round) instead of `CAST` — or in addition to `CAST` — when converting your `score` to an integer.

Comment: Ruakh are you for hire? Once again to my rescue. Thanks ruakh